# Using reloadData as an insurance policy on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a rather complex data source for my UITableView.  I am very carefully keeping it in sync with the tableview itself, inserting and removing rows/sections manually (with animation)  whenever some data changes, and vice versa.

It is hard to be 100% confident in my ability to keep these matched up.  The effects of a mis-match between the view and the data can be severe - for example, selecting a row and trying to do something to the associated object, when that object does not exist, will cause a crash. Many other bugs would lead to less obvious errors (operating on the wrong object, for example).

I was thinking about how all of this goes away if I call reloadData after each data change instead of manually modifying the view. But then I would lose the animation.

So perhaps I could somehow call reloadData **after** my animations have ended, as a safety measure.

- Does this sound like a good idea?  Any alternatives?
- Where would I place this call so that the reload only occurs after animation (and would thus be invisible to the user if all is well)?
- Is there anything I could do to compare the view before and after reloadData, to identify if anything changed on the screen and throw a warning, for debugging purposes?  I expect this would only work on rows that are in view, since offscreen content is dequeued only when required.

Interested in your thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain.  Unfortunately, I don't think that the reload idea helps much.  If there's a discrepancy between the model and the table view, in my experience the problem manifests as an exception *before or during* the update animations.  If there's a problem, I've found that you don't make it to the reload, and I don't think you want to.

These are some risk factors that, in my experience, lead to  models prone to get out of synch with a table view:

- model count and model items that come from more complex calculations
  than simple array counts and array itemAtIndex:
- filters, like tabs that show a different aspect of the model in the same table based on which tab is selected
- search results controller and it's tableView
- updates based on events that are triggered asynchronously
- heterogenous types in the model, with different cell types and sizes
- one clumsy word: FetchedResultsController
- and especially combinations of the above

This goes a little beyond table views, and, I don't claim to be a perfect practitioner of all the preaching here, but I think the way to get confidence in your app includes the following:

1. Build the UI with no art and as little app logic as possible; just a
   mock version of the model - to the extent possible - equal in
   complexity but not in volume, to the real thing.
2. Build the model and app logic, along with tests that - to the extent
   possible - exercise it independently of the UI.
3. While you're testing, embrace exceptions as your friend, telling you that you need a fix.  *Insert as little defensive code as you can for as long as possible*.

My $0.02.  Best of luck.

Comment: This is good advice.  I'll leave this open a while to see if anyone has a direct way to trigger a reload after animations, though it seems less like a good idea given your response.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line of code wherever you do your insert/remove row animations.

```
   [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTheTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];  




-(void) reloadTheTable {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

However with some more time I think you could figure out how to do your remove add rows without bugs and then the extra reloadData would not be required, but your table may be more complicated than what I've worked with.